# Function call after waiting "X" seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I'm doing some sort of loop with Ajax. As each request, the function is called again for the next. I wish after the end of the AJAX request, the function was called again only after waiting 200 ms / 2 seconds, for example.

How can I do this? 
Below is my current code.

```
      var mailIDs = [1, 2];
      var timeout = 200;

      function sendMail() {
        if (mailIDs.length > 0) {
          var mailID = mailIDs.shift();

          assunto = $("input[name=assunto]").val();
          conteudo = $("#editor1").val();

          data = "mailID=" + mailID + "&assunto=" + assunto + "&conteudo=" + conteudo;

          $.ajax({
            url: "ajax/sendMail.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(resultMail) {
              alert(resultMail);

              // Call the function sendMail() after X ms (timeout).

              sendMail();
            }
          })

        }
      }

      sendMail();
```

Comment: You have almost answered your own question in your comment... use `setTimeout()` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) like this;

```
success: function (resultMail) {
    alert(resultMail);

    // Call the function sendMail() after X ms (timeout).
    setTimeout(sendMail, timeout);   // As Anthony points out in the comments 
}
```

Comment: Or just `setTimeout(sendMail, timeout)` since it has no parameters; no reason to use an anonymous function.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Oh! LOL I know not why I wrote it like that. was in a hurry I think. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 setTimeout(function(){sendMail();},timeout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [setTimeout() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
setTimeout(function(){
   sendMail();
}, 2000);
```

Or, like this:

```
 setTimeout(sendMail, 2000);
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong (was wrong, now corrected) and will call `sendMail` immediately.

Comment: or `setTimeout(sendMail, 2000);`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is easy to do like this:

```
setTimeout(sendMail, 2000);
```

You don't need any extra wrapping functions for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()` or `setInterval()` plain javascript functions.
See more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)